# Show that orthogonal projection of $(0,1,0)$ over $W$ is the vector $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{i}{2}, \frac{1+i}{4})$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Given $W = Sp\{(1,i,0),(1,2,1-i)\}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$ with the standard inner product.

Show that the orthogonal projection of $(0,1,0)$ over $W$ is the vector $(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, \frac{i}{2}, \frac{1+i}{4})$.

I tried computing it but $W$ is not orthogonal, so how does one approach this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "$W$ is not orthogonal"? By the way, you can start by finding an orthonormal basis for $W$.

Comment: @azif00 the vectors of $W$ aren't orthogonal to each other, and the process of finding an orthonormal basis requires an orthogonal basis

Comment: @Tomergt45, you can use the Gram-Schmidt Orthogonalization process to get an orthonormal basis for $W$ after which the orthogonal projection will be easy to compute.

Comment: @Tomergt45 Nope, the process of finding an orthonormal basis requires only linear independence. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).